# Mule Jersey module with Jersey2.0 or later

Tags: module, jersey, mule

As of now Mule Jersey module supports only jersey1.6 or previous Jersey release. Our whole webservice(API) is written in jersey2.0 or later. So we've a version conflicts as so many things are changed in jersey2.0

Is there any idea when Mule Jersey module starts supporting jersey2.0 or later version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.6.0 onwards Mule ESB will use Jersey 2.11. Source: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7842

Comment: Awesome. I saw 3.6.0-M2 has upgraded Jersey. Any idea when 3.6.0-M2 Enterprise and GA Enterprise version will be out?

Comment: From where and How can I  download Mule 3.6.0-M2?

Comment: It isn't available yet. 3.6.0-M2 will be release as part of a beta program targeted to Enterprise and Community users, please keep a look on our [blog](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/) to get more details, it should be during the next few weeks. The productive 3.6.0 version will probably be released in January, but date is still open.